# Retrieving an object array from a document after a change has been made in firestore through cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore document with a field called items, which is an array of objects making each item. Here is the structure:

```
- Document1
              | document_status
              | items
                     | item1
                     |   | name
                     |   | item_status
                     | item2
                     |   | name
                     |   | item_status
```

Right now I am listening to document updates using onUpdate() method which works fine. Eg: If the document_status changes then I am getting the change in the change.after.data() method. But I need to get a reference to the 'items' field through the **change.after.ref** so that I can go through each items and change the *item_status*

**I only want to access the document through the **change** and not directly. Because I am using wildcards to retrieve the document reference**

I saw a close example here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/limit-children/functions/index.js#L27-L39 but unfortunately i couldn't try to go deeper and get a reference for the *items* child.

This is what i tried:

```
exports.sampleFunction = functions.firestore
        .document(‘mycollection/{documentId}/subCollection/{mydocuments}’).onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const newData = change.after.data();
        const documentStatus = newData.document_status;
         const parentRef = change.after.ref.child("items");
          return parentRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((item) => {
              updates[item.item_status] = "some_value"
            });
            return parentRef.update(updates);
          });
        }
        return;
    });
```

I also tried using:

change.after.ref.parent.child("items");

and different combinations. But I am getting an error as below:

```
TypeError: change.after.ref.child is not a function
    at exports.sample_function.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/user_code/index.js:31:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Please suggest how I can go through all the items and update all the **item_status** to some_value

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this: "I only want to access the document through the change and not directly. Because I am using wildcards to retrieve the document reference".  Could you edit your question to explain better what that means?  Also, I think it would be great if you showed the entire function you're working with, not just a few lines of it.  We should be able to see the way you're defining your function.

Comment: You have another major problem in that you say you're using Firestore, but your code seems to be using APIs that looks like Realtime Database access.

Comment: Thank you for your response @DougStevenson i have updated my question with the full function. By "I only want to access the document through the change and not directly.", means that I have a wildcard in my path, so i want my function to trigger whenever someone tries to change any document belonging in the given path. I really appreciate if you can point me in the right direction. I used this firebase doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing_data) to get an idea on how I could get the ref to the document.

Comment: But unfortunately I find it difficult to get a reference of a child and get its children array.

Comment: Use the Firestore API to deal with documents and document references, not the Realtime Database APIs.  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you. The document was useful and I understood the capabilities of firestore. I wanted to updated only one property (eg: item_status) inside the array elements belonging to a document field. But it seems like I can't do that. I have to update the entire field (Eg: items (all array elements)) by applying {merge: true}. Have you worked on something similar to this? Is there a better way to do this?